# how to get the selected text value using this in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectbox

I need to get the selected option text in jQuery of a select box.I used

```
   $('#selectId :selected').text();
```

It is working fine for me.But how i can do this with following.Here i am iterating all 
   select boxes which have a particular class.I used following code.But it is not working 
   for me.

```
 $('.className').each(function(index,value){
    alert($(this :selected).text());
  });
```

It is giving the error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Please help me .Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's incorrect syntax. You could use:

```
$('.className').each(function(index,value){
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

or as an alternative:

```
$('.className').each(function(index,value){
    alert($("option:selected", this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See `.className` is a collection itself so you can use it this way on the event of `change` get the `option:selected` of it and then alert text of it.

```
$('.className').on('change', function(){
   alert($("option:selected", this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
 $('.className').each(function(index,value){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      { alert($(this).val());}
  });
```

Comment: but i am using select box.How i can  use this